# checking and insertion of email in database using data model popup through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

```
public function register()
    {   

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|is_unique[register.email]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){



            $this->load->view('view/login_register');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error','This id is already taken');

        }
        else
        {
           ///$username=$this->input->post('username');
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $data= array(

             ////'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
                'email'=>$email,   
          //'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                );

            $last_id=$this->model->registeration($data);

            if ($last_id>0) {

                $this->send_email($email);


                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'To complete registration, click the link in email we just send you at khadija@precisetech.com.pk');
                redirect('controller/register');
            }


        } 
    if(error_flag == 1){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

how to do this through Ajax if Id exist give message that id already exist, the data model popup should be there without refreshing the page and display messsage in the datamodel popup means the datmodel popup should be stay till message success or failur.

Comment: you should do this on blur function of jquery . when user write email id then on blur you send and request to an function for with response true or false which is decide user email is exist or not https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: that is not best way I have datamodel popup and the popup should be there till reponse. true or false message. through ajax.